# Set request headers for a Ext.data.Store proxy in SenchaTouch

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, iphone, sencha-touch

I have a data Store that gets it's information from a JSON api on my server.  When I run the code in WebKit/Chrome everything appears to work fine, but if I change my user-agent to iPhone 4.1, etc it appears that the JSON requests aren't getting set properly.  Instead of sending a request to get JSON it simply sends the request and gets the HTML rendered page instead.

This is the Store that I have defined:

```
Product.ProductStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Product',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/admin/products.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'products'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'productStore',
    getGroupString: function(record){
        return record.get('vendor')[0];
    }
});
```

So what I really want to have this store do is send a request to /admin/products.json, which works as expected on the desktop.  But when I run this in my Simulator or even on a Device it appears to be just sending the request to /admin/products which returns the HTML instead.

Some people have suggested that this is a rails server issue and I need to set the content type for my request.  The problem is how do I exactly do this?

I've tried the following, and it doesn't appear to work either:

```
Product.ProductStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Product',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/admin/products.json',
            // Trying to set the headers for the request -- not working
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'products'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'productStore',
    getGroupString: function(record){
        return record.get('vendor')[0];
    }
});
```

Could I simply replace the AJAX request with my own that has the content-type headers set properly? If so, are there some examples which use a store and it's own custom AJAX request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
'Accept' : 'application/json'
```

Accept is a header the client uses to tell the server what media-type it prefers.
Content-Type is a header that the server sends as part of the response telling the client what the data is.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working, I've tried setting defaultHeaders and headers in my proxy object but it still doesn't appear to be setting the request headers properly.

Comment: Did you replace Content-Type with Accept. You reply isn't clear. When running it in chrome use the developer tools to check the headers on the request.

Comment: Turned out it was a server-side UA detection bug that would always redirect any requests to /admin/products. Apologies for being vague, I meant that I had indeed tried your suggestion. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for Ext.Ajax.request when making a call to the asp.net mcv4 WebApi. MVC4 seems to read the accept header and then give a response based on that.